# Parse CSV in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, amazon-s3

I currently have a .csv that I am getting from S3 and trying to read the file in using the following command:

```
for i in range(0, 50):
response = s3.get_object(Bucket = b, Key = a['ColumnName'].iloc[i])
file = response['Body'].read()
tempdf = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(file), sep=r',(?!\s)')
```

The issue is that the .csv that is being parsed has text with commas in it and is throwing off the column alignment. The columns are also not blocked off with quoting and there is no option to change the raw file.

Comment: Set your separator to something that doesn't exist so everything is loaded into a single column. Then write rules to split out your columns, accounting for the columns that occur within the text.

Comment: @flyingmeatball what type of rules would one write?

Comment: That's really hard to know without knowing your data looks. You need some way to identify which commas are part of text blocks and which are identifying new columns, I can't tell you that without your data.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of your CSV data, this would make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Update: I am going to be using a regular expression to parse the file.